# Provide Swashbuckle example for parent class method

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a generic WebApi controller base class that implements a set of standard routes. I am now trying to provide an example with SwaggerRequestExample. Is there a way to influence the parent class method's annotation from the child class? Or can this be done through configuration or code instead of annotation?

Example

```
public abstract class GenericController<T> : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost]
  public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] T entity)
  {
    var result = await _service.GetFromDb()
    //the result is depending on T; so each implementing child class
    //needs to have it's own example
    return Ok(result);
  }
}


public class StudentController : GenericController<Student> { }
```

There is no place to put
[SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(StudentRespnseExample))]

Comment: Could you pls offer an example to explain your goal more vividly? How to understand the sentence `influence the parent class method's annotation from the child class` ?

Comment: Hey Tiny, I added a one-liner at the end of my question. Maybe that helps. In the meantime, I also found a solution that is working and doesnt add too much code.

Comment: Thanks for reply and it's fine you got the solution : )

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially a solution that can work. However, it still doesnt generate the example. There is some other pieces I am missing in my config. Unfortunately, I dont have time to investigate right now. Will come back later again.

```
public class StudentController : GenericController<Student>
{
  [HttpPost]
  [SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(StudentResponseExample))]
  public override async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Student entity)
  {
    return await base.Create(entity);
  }

}
```